# QGIS import python module [Mac OS]

Tags: python, module, qgis

I am working on QGIS and I installed networkx module in python but when I import it in the QGIS python console it say

```
ImportError: No module named networkx.readwrite
```

my PYTHONPATH is:

> /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python

As I understand QGIS on Mac OS use the default python so there should be no error importing module to QGIS if it work in python console so I don't know what's wrong.